# Dygraphs: Adding annotation to my time-series

Tags: datetime, time-series, dygraphs

I am continuing to play with Dygraphs with time-series. I have followed the documentation here:
http://dygraphs.com/annotations.html
and here: http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/annotations

My x-axis is a javascript Date() object. Upon inspection, an example of my time-series array that I use with Dygraphs is as follows:

```
[[Wed Sep 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time), 5.311174814188838, 11],
[Wed Sep 25 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time), 5.313242976801092, 11],
[Wed Sep 25 2013 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time), 5.310303423288409, 11],
[Wed Sep 25 2013 03:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time), 5.301762506225051, 11]]
```

The series could be "A" and "B". No matter how I try to set the annotation, it does not work. For example,

```
annDate = new Date('2013 09 25');
g.setAnnotations([
{
  series: "A",
  x: annDate,
  shortText: "L",
  text: "Coldest Day"
}
]);
```

I have tried directly specifying the date as a string such as "2013-09-25" etc. but I cannot get the annotation to display on the graph.

***EDIT***
Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/be8s6/3/

Comment: Please provide a demo link, preferably via dygraphs.com/fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/be8s6/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/be8s6/4/

The trick is to express your annotation as:

```
{
  series: "A",
  x: new Date("2009/07/12 14:00").getTime(),
  shortText: "L",
  text: "Coldest Day"
}
```

i.e. the `x` value should be in milliseconds since epoch. This is admittedly a bit confusing.

Comment: Sure thing - should have thought of this. Thank you very much.

Comment: danvk: In a previous post you may recall that I was playing with collapsing the weekends or where there is empty data. You mentioned that time on the x-axis is continuous. However, when I try to place an event at a time that dose not have an explicit data point associated with it in the series, it fails to display. Instead, my events must occur at a moment when there is a real data point. This is not how I would have expected it to work given that time is meant to be continuous. Am I missing something?

Comment: there's a bug filed in dygraphs that you can only add annotations at data points.  https://code.google.com/p/dygraphs/issues/detail?id=310&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: Yup, I actually run an algorithm that steps through my timeseries and adds in data points at the date/time where I want to add my annotations.

Comment: You just have saved me another 5h :)